# Push Notification badge clears alert

Tags: iphone, push-notification

When I send a push notification without an alert, just a badge, it clears whatever alert is onscreen. The opposite is also true. Sending an alert without a badge clears the badge.

Is there any way to push a new badge without affecting any current alerts on screen?

Answer (score 0):

It seems only intuitive that the latest notification for an app is considered as the most updated one, and show only those attributes that accompany it.

Also, the "Quality of Service" for push notifications specify that delivery of all the notifications is never guaranteed, except the last one.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9

So you must never count on previous notifications, and must send the most updated info with each one.

Comment: But don't you think it is reasonable to want to update the unread count without clearing the last alert?

Comment: Well, its a design issue and Apple has kept it simple on their part for sure. So there is no concept of updating-the-last-sent-notification(or badge or alert) here and every notification should be treated as the "only one that has even been sent" and also as the "only one that is ever gonna be sent". :)